# ASP.NET_SessionId cookie is undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-cookies

I am working on ASP.NET MVC application. I want to access sessionid in javascript, so for this i was trying to read an ASP.NET_SessionId cookie in javascript:

```
=>  $.cookie("ASP.NET_SessionId")
=>  undefined
```

but i am getting undefined. Can anybody tell me how can i access the sessionId cookie ?

Answer (score 11):

**You cannot access the session cookie** because it is set to [HTTP Only](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly).

so it is hidden from JavaScript for security reasons. It would be a massive security flaw to expose it to JavaScript.

[This coding horror blog talks about how cookies are protected from Javascript](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html)